# Selenium Ajax wait_for_condition

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, element, wait

I am using Selenium with the Python scripting and I am trying to use the wait_for_condition function.

I want to wait for the element defined by this xpath :

```
"/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]"
```

to be present so I am trying the following :

```
sel.wait_for_condition(
    "var x = selenium.browserbot.findElementOrNull('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]'); x != null && x.style.display == 'none';", "5000");
```

But it doesn't work, could someone tell me what is incorrect please ?

Thank you very much,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The timeout, 5000, should be given as an integer, not a string:

```
sel.wait_for_condition(
    "var x = selenium.browserbot.findElementOrNull('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]'); x != null && x.style.display == 'none';",
    5000)
```

Also from the docs:

> ```
>     Note that, by default, the snippet will be run in the runner's test window, not in the window
>     of your application.  To get the window of your application, you can use
>     the JavaScript snippet ``selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()``, and then
>     run your JavaScript in there.
> ```

Comment: I tried this one you gave me but I still have the same problem. I am sure of the xpath expression 
Maybe something is wrong somewhere else ?